# Wordpress custom endpoint template doesn’t load

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend

I’m trying to add custom template `account-details.php` to my new endpoint in my-account area.

I have added the new account-details endpoint first:

```
add_action( 'init', 'co_add_my_account_endpoint' );

function co_add_my_account_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'account-details', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
```

and here I’m adding the custom template:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'co_custom_endpoint', 10, 5 );
/**
* Add account details custom template
*
* @param $located
* @param $template_name
* @param $args
* @param $template_path
* @param $default_path
* @since 2.0
* @return string $located
*/
function co_custom_endpoint($located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path) {
    global $wp;

    if( 'myaccount/my-account.php' == $template_name ) {
        $located = wc_locate_template( 'myaccount/account-details.php', $template_path, JGTB_PATH . 'templates/' );
    }

    return $located;
}
```

At the end I flush rewrite rules manually, but my template is still not loading on frontend. Anyone can see what am I doing wrong?
I have found other posts on stack-overflow regarding this, but if I replicate exactly the same it doesn’t work for me either.. any ideas?

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code to your active theme's `function.php`.

```
function custom_account_details_page_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'account-details', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_account_details_page_endpoints' );

function custom_account_details_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'account-details';

    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_account_details_query_vars', 0 );

function custom_account_details_query_vars_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'custom_account_details_query_vars_flush_rewrite_rules' );
```

Be sure to place the `account-details.php` file in the `myaccount` folder.

```
function custom_account_details_endpoint_content() {
    include 'woocommerce/myaccount/account-details.php'; 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_account-details_endpoint', 'custom_account_details_endpoint_content' );
```

By doing this make sure to update permalinks by going to Dashboard -> settings -> permalinks and clik on `save settings`

Comment: Thank you loads @raju_eww! This has been a great help and the code works fine :) I was offline for few days, so only replying now..